Recommendations for project management software
Does anyone have a recommendation for project management software that is well-suited for academia? I am thinking something along the lines of monday.com, asana, jira, etc.
Some of the example applications that I envision are:

Managing a grant submission: letting collaborators know deadlines for budgets, narrative contributions, etc. I often have half a dozen grants in the pipeline, and it is a nightmare trying to keep track of what is due when.
Managing a project with graduate students: giving grad students/postdocs tasks (e.g. presentation for this conference, submit manuscript for my review, etc)
Teaching a course: managing deadlines for me and my TAs for creating / uploading / grading assignments and exams.
Managing committees and service duties: deadlines for reviewing faculty applications, submitting minisymposium proposals, that kind of thing.

My non-negotiable requirements are:

Inexpensive (< $300/year). We do not have lots of money to burn on non-essentials. Ideally the software would have an academic plan option.
Work well with external collaborators without forcing them to create an account. I don't want to force an entire project management ecosystem on my colleagues. When I assign an item to an external colleague, I want them to (for example) receive an email and maybe a calendar invitation, with a button that they can click when the item is completed. (Every service I've tried so far requires external collaborators to create an account.)

Ideally, this would also integrate with cloud services such as slack, office 365, canvas, and workday.
I've tried most of the big players, but none of them seem to be a good fit. Has anyone had success with project management software in academia, and can you recommend any products or services that work well?

Just a reminder that while questions like this would normally be considered a "shopping question," there is an exception for software recommendations.

Working at all with external collaborators seems like a tall order. Personally, I've never had a research collaborator ask me to use software like this. However, various admin units (e.g. advising) have adopted similar software, and I've gotten frustrating automated emails "assigning" me work where it's not clear what I'm being asked to do, who to contact with questions, or whether this is actually my responsibility at all. That said, adopting something just for yourself and those you supervise seems like a very interesting idea, and I'm curious to read the answers.

@academic Exactly. I have no interest in forcing a complex system on my overworked colleagues. On the other hand, I need to clearly communicate deadlines to them and to keep track of the deadlines myself. (This is done extremely poorly in academa IMHO)
The ideal format would be based on simple calendar invitations, which are universal and platform independent. Second-best would be emails with a one-click "mark completed" button, and the option to add automatic reminders until completed.

@mrp I'm not sure that even these calendar invitations are universal. My email client supports them, as does pretty much everybody's, but I don't use the underlying calendaring software to manage my schedule.

I'm a research administrator who works in Engineering.  For complex proposals, I am having my team show deadlines in Clickup to help explain the workloads and how the tasks flow into each other, which is often difficult for PIs to visualize.  Here's an example of a Gannt made on a free account.  We submitted a MURI with 4 subs, and we showed the PI this during meetings to show how we were crunching tasks into the end of the timeline prior to submission.  It was helpful to show that pushing tasks off was increasing the burden to the PI (and right before the new semester started).
In some ways, the exact software package is less important than the commitment to use it as a team and deal with what the software tells you-- e.g., when you are running out of time and need to reprioritize efforts.  Some people respond well to this level of organization, but not all of your collaborators will.  Just be mindful of who you are working with and their own knowledge of project management.  Even with senior PIs, this varies a lot.  Some people are actually really put off by this level of organization.  They find it micromanaging.
If you are the one leading the use of the software, this also is easier than asking staff or other collaborators to learn the software for you.  You may find that if you use the visual in a meeting and ask others to help you tweak the deadlines as time moves forward that you can get through the organization process pretty quickly with the least amount of negotiating with other parties.  I've worked with well-organized PIs like this in the past, and they tend to get funded because they have a great command over the process, but they do take on a lot of the burden themselves.


Thanks for the answer. I agree that this level of detail is micromanaging. MURI is a great example. I do not want to overload PIs with a complex system and a bunch of individual tasks. For a project like this, I want to give them maybe 3-4 hard deadlines (budget due, your portion of the narrative due, etc.). I am happy if they only see this through email and maybe calendar.

Yes, in this example, there are subtasks for each sub, where we show that we will ask for all of the documents in the sub package.  We only shared this Gannt with the PI and no one else.  On this project, we started down the path of the sub package, and then part-way through, we ran into problems with the budget split, and then the PI had to see that this set us back at square one for all subs -- which pushed out all the downstream deadlines.  It helps for people to see the impact of simple errors and how important it is to get the decision correct so you don't have to redo work.
